# Windows + Docker + WSL2

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, wsl2

I am starting with Docker on Windows. Simple examples work fine. But now I would like to install Laravvel 8 container which requires WSL2 installed with Docker desktop. According [Microsoft doc.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) it requires to join insiders program and install OS build 20262 or higher (I have 18363). While insiders registration there is a IMPORTANT NOTICE which says:

> The experimental and early prerelease software and services made
> available to you in the Program might not be tested. You might
> experience crashes, security vulnerabilities, data loss, or damage to
> your device. ...

What it means? I dont want this warranty of troubles. Is it possible to run docker without WSL2? I dont understnd it. Another users says WSL2 on Win is buggy. It does not sound good. What sould I do if I want to start with Docker?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: It means you will have to wait until 21H1 is released within the next 3 months or upgrade to the current Insider Preview build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it requires to join insiders program and install OS build 20262 or higher (I have 18363).

WSL2 requires 1909 or newer, which is what you have installed, which means you could use Docker today without upgrading to an Insider Preview build.  What requires 21H1 is a simplified installer.  The simplified installer isn’t required to use Docker within WSL2.

> What it means?

It means Insider Preview builds are experimental and are not always stable.  If your not willing to deal with potentially unsolvable issues you shouldn’t upgrade to an Insider Preview build.

> Is it possible to run docker without WSL2?

It’s always been possible to run Docker on Windows.  It just requires Hyper-V if I am not mistaken.

> What sould I do if I want to start with Docker?

Only you can decide if you want to install Docker at this point. My opinion on the matter would not be helpful.

Comment: So I explained the documentation.  My opinion with regards if you should use Docker isn’t helpful though. **It’s also out of scope.**